# Visual Studio 2015: Cant see any type of project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, empty-list

I have a problem with VS 2015 Professional Edition.
I install it on 2 PC ( a PC with windows 8.1 and other PC with windows 10 ) and i have the same problem: I can't see ant project on my New Project list.
Have someone this problem and know a answer ? If you know what can i do please help me. Here is a printscreen:

[image]

I want to mention that when I open VS 2015 I receive a warning message:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a very broken installation. try clearing the ComponentModelCache, if that doesn't work, repair Visual Studio. If that doesn't work do a force uninstall (vs_setup /uninstall /force) and reinstall it.

often these issues are caused by a Add-in which ships with an assembly on which Visual Studio itself also depends (but is of a different version).

Comment: I want to say that I have installed VS Ultimate 2013 and work perfectly. But i want to switch on 2015 and i greet this problem.